# SharePoint Lookup Column - Number Format to remove commas

Tags: json, sharepoint, format, lookup

I have a lookup column in SharePoint 2019 that is looking back to a number field from a custom list.

I used the following JSON to format the lookup column to display the number without the hyperlink:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue"
}
```

**I want to also remove the thousands commas to display the numbers from 1,234 to just 1234**

Any suggestions on how this can be done simply? Seems odd there is no simple option to change the view format. (P.S. my JSON coding ability isn't great!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, some are a bit hack-ish but work:
if you are using **Modern List Experience** you can simply achieve this by applying following conditional formatting JSON to the number column in your lookup list:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField > 0,'', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

For **Classic Experience** a workaround could be to keep the data type of  your `number` column as `single line of text` in your lookup list and apply the following formula in *column validation section*:

```
=ISNUMBER([text-column-name]+0)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Muhammad Murad Haider, thanks for the response, I am using the Modern Experience and applied the above JSON to the number column in the lookup list but the problem still exists. Any suggestions why this might be?

Comment: hmm.. need to look into that for lookup columns. but second approach would work fine for both classic or modern experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below json code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "=substring(@currentField.lookupValue,0,1)",           
            "=substring(@currentField.lookupValue,2,6)"
        ]   
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `txtContent` to `=replace(@currentField.lookupValue, ',', '')`:

```
{      
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json", 
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replace(@currentField.lookupValue, ',', '')"   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should format your code as code and add some kind of explanation.